# Faster SQL query for over 2 million rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of tables I'm joining to do a search query. This query allows several optional parameters. But the main table that it is searching (`T_AS400_BLRPIN00`) has over 2 million rows.

When I run the execution plan, most of the time spent is on a nonclustered index scan.

The table (T_AS400_BLRPIN00) has 38 columns, I won't list them all here (unless you feel it is necessary) but some of the key fields are:

```
INSPASER (int, null) -- Part of the old key  
INSPIND (varchar(1), null) -- The other part of the old key  
T_AS400_BLRPIN00_ID (PK, int, not null) -- The new key
```

The Index that is used looks like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX01_T_AS400_BLRPIN00] 
ON [dbo].[T_AS400_BLRPIN00] 
(
    [INSPASER] ASC,
    [INSPIND] ASC
)
```

My stored procedure / query searches the table like this:

```
FROM
    dbo.T_AS400_BLRPIN00 AS Insp
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.T_AS400_BLRPEQP00 AS Eqp ON Insp.T_AS400_BLRPEQP00_ID = Eqp.T_AS400_BLRPEQP00_ID
WHERE
    (@pint_INSPASER=0 OR Insp.INSPASER = @pint_INSPASER)
    AND 
    (ISNULL(INSPIND,'') like '%' + @pstr_INSPIND + '%')
```

I don't like searching such a large table with a `varchar`, but for now we need that ability. Sometimes `@pstr_INSPIND` is an empty string ('') because they are not searching by that, sometimes it is a single char().

The execution plan shows the index scan (nonclustered) to take 63%, and then the Nested Loop (Inner Join) to the Key Lookup takes 36%.

Is there a better way I can engineer this?

Comment: The query might be fine try to run your proc `WITH RECOMPILE` option or OPTION recompile. http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/using-recompile-query-hint-solve-parameter-sniffing-problems

Comment: Why do you need a LIKE clause on a VARCHAR(1) field?  Based on your field size, pstr_ISPIND can only ever be one character, so remove the LIKE and % and just use an equals sign

Comment: Would be easier to help with the actual execution plan. But do you need the ISNULL(INSPIND)? Since you wrapped your column in a function it will force a scan no matter what because it has to evaluate every single row.

Comment: @SeanLange I think `coalesce` worked pretty well in this format (still allowing the use of the index, unlike the `like '%abc%'`), but yeah, this query does not really need it anyway.

Comment: Also a little hint,IF your column  INSPIND is declared NOT NULL your ISNULL is ignored so it can use an index.

Comment: @pstr_INSPIND is filled from a dropdown list. Possible values are: 'B', 'V', ''. '' means find all records. :/ Don't shoot the messanger. :) Perhaps I could do (@pstr_INSPIND = '' OR INSPIND = @pstr_INSPIND)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this

```
  WHERE

(@pint_INSPASER=0 OR Insp.INSPASER = @pint_INSPASER)
AND 
(ISNULL(INSPIND,'') like '%' + @pstr_INSPIND + '%')
```

to this

```
  WHERE
    (@pint_INSPASER=0 OR Insp.INSPASER = @pint_INSPASER)
    AND 
    (INSPIND = @pstr_INSPIND or INSPIND is NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `like '%abc%'` is deadly - you're not using the index at all.

So you'll likely get a better performance by removing it from the composite index altogether.

Also, if possible, try reducing the search so that you're doing `like 'abc%'` instead - that can in fact use the index. Also, why are you using `%` at all on a `varchar(1)` column?

Answer (score 0):

The "like" is bad. Also, what is in that variable (@pstr_INSPIND)? [Parameter sniffing?](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/)

What are your statistics like? Estimated vs actual rows returned?

Not sure how are you populating @pstr_INSPIND but you might be open to sqlinjection.